# python repeats function 3 times

Tags: python, user-input

The purpose of this code is to:

1. Ask the user to enter his name.
2. Ask the user to enter his date of birth
3. The code will split the name into first, middle and last name
4. The code will calculate the age in years, months and days.
5. The code will store all these data in a dictionary

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


    class Test:
        def __init__(self):
            self.today = datetime.today()
    
        def name(self):
            first_name, middle_name, last_name = input("enter your name:\n".title()).split(' ')
            return first_name, middle_name, last_name
    
        def age(self):
            date_of_birth = input("enter your date of birth:\n")
            date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d/%m/%Y")
            age = relativedelta(self.today, date_of_birth)
            return age
    
        def data(self):
            data = {"first name": self.name()[0],
                    "middle_name": self.name()[1],
                    "last name": self.name()[2],
                    "age years": self.age().years,
                    "age months": self.age().months,
                    "age days": self.age().days}
            print(data)
    
    
    Test().data()
```

The code makes no error.

But the question for the name and the age repeated three times for each.
something like this

enter your date of birth:

26/9/1986

enter your date of birth:

26/9/1986

enter your date of birth:

26/9/1986

Comment: Every time you call `self.age` (which you do three times), it asks the questions, similarly with `self.name`

Comment: `self.name()` is called the name function. Call it once, store the result in a variable then build the dict

Comment: You should assign `self.name()` to a variable before loading its elements into the `data` dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `age()` three times. You could call it once, and then access its members:

```
def data(self):
    name = self.name()
    age = self.age()
    data = {"first name": name[0],
            "middle_name": name[1],
            "last name": name[2],
            "age years": age.years,
            "age months": age.months,
            "age days": age.days}
    print(data)
```

Comment: You don't want to split the name like that

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use instances and call the name input in init method itself as below:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.today = datetime.today()
        self.full_name = input("enter your full name:\n".title()).split(' ')
        self.dob = input("enter your date of birth:\n")

    @property
    def name(self):
        first_name, middle_name, last_name = self.full_name
        return first_name, middle_name, last_name

    @property
    def age(self):
        date_of_birth = self.dob
        date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d/%m/%Y")
        age = relativedelta(self.today, date_of_birth)
        return age

    def data(self):
        data = {"first name": self.name[0],
                "middle_name": self.name[1],
                "last name": self.name[2],
                "age years": self.age.years,
                "age months": self.age.months,
                "age days": self.age.days}
        print(data)
```

so You will be actually initializing value you need as input in `__init__` method when you instantiate class object and then use the data method any time you need to use, it will store the values to the variable until you reinstantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling each of `self.age` and `self.name` three times. You should call each of them once only, and save the result into the relevant variables.

Maybe it would be good to set these variables as properties of the instance for future use, but as a minimum fix to the problem, here is a version of `data` that performs the relevant calls only once.

```
    def data(self):

        first_name, middle_name, last_name = self.name()
        
        age = self.age()
        
        data = {"first name": first_name,
                "middle_name": middle_name,
                "last name": last_name,
                "age years": age.years,
                "age months": age.months,
                "age days": age.days}
        print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `name` and `age` functions re-prompt the user for fresh input each time you call them.  It might be better to cache them; you could do this yourself by storing it as an instance attribute, or just use `functools.lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache

...

    @lru_cache
    def name(self):
        first_name, middle_name, last_name = input("enter your name:\n".title()).split(' ')
        return first_name, middle_name, last_name

    @lru_cache
    def age(self):
        date_of_birth = input("enter your date of birth:\n")
        date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d/%m/%Y")
        age = relativedelta(self.today, date_of_birth)
        return age
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to use lru cache